# Calling methods directly from a list filled with objectsA from objectB in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, methods

I'm trying to call methods from a list that is filled with objects from a different class where the list is defined.

Consider the following:

```
class ObjectA(object):
    def __init__(self, object_id):
        self.id = object_id
    def a_function(self):
        return self.id

from ObjectA import ObjectA
class ObjectB:
    def test():
        object_1 = ObjectA(1) # passing the id
        a_list = [ObjectA] # setting the list to be of type ObjectA (?)
        a_list.append(object_1)
        a_list[0].a_function() # Says I need to pass argument 'self'
```

How something like this would be possible? I know that I could instead do a_list[0].id and it works but it feels wrong. I prefer having setters/getters.

Edit: I'm also aware that if I declare the list like this a_list = [] instead of a_list = [ObjectA] it also works but in that case I don't have access to the methods for autocompletion.

Comment: An IDE like Spyder or PyCharm would handle auto completion in such a situation. This is not an issue with your code, but with your editor.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm and it does autocomplete with the code I wrote above, however the code doesn't run It's needs "self" in the method.

Comment: Read my answer, the ˋself` problem comes from your `a_list = [ObjectA]ˋ. Don’t write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can't specify the type of a list. So the line `a_list = [ObjectA]` makes no sense. (In fact it creates a list containing the class `ObjectA`, not an object, hence the `self` error.)

Replace `a_list = [ObjectA]` with `a_list = []` to create an empty list

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of the a_list = [] but I was hoping for a better solution that would allow for autompletition and making the list accept a spesific type of objects even though this isn't really how Python works. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: A list never has a specific type in Python. You can even create a list like `['a', 1]`, each value is independant. The same goes for the variables. You can do `a=1` and then `a='a'`, it will work.